# Angular.js common code dislocation

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I need to something like before_action or common application_controller, that includes all common functional for other controllers and actions and pages and modules.

Typical example: e-store with 3 types of pages (products page, product info page, cart page) and I need login facebook for view cart, binded for FB id, but i can to login on every page, not only on cart page...

How it does in angularjs (without rails and something else)?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into partials. You can use a seperate controller (`facebookLoginCtrl`) for your login. Then you can just use this partial wherever you need it.

Comment: do you mean include partial (by "ng-include" or separate custom directive) with "ng-controller" directive, that will include all business logic of authenticate?